# Application is not loaded after upgrading Ember v.1.5

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data, ember-testing

I have updated my ember v1.5 from v1.4. After that my application not getting rendered. 
In my application, I am using _super() in lot of places. Does it make problem. And I am using require.js as well.

I debug through app, and I found its triggered indexRoute. But after that nothing is happen. Below is my route structure,

***Route Map:***

```
App.Router.map(function() {
    this.resource('public', { path: '/public' }, function() {
        this.route('login');
        this.route('logout');
    });
});

Ember.Router.reopen({
    transitionTo : function(name, param) {
        .......
        //Handling my  own code here
        .......
        this._super(name);
    }
});

App.BaseRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    setup : function(context) {
        var thatSuper = this._super;
        require(_rp, function() {
                .......
                //Handling my  own code here
                .......
                thatSuper.call(self, context);
                ........
        }, function(error){
            ...Handling error.....
        });
    },
    renderTemplate : function(router, context) {
        window.scrollTo(0, 0);
    }
});

App.IndexRoute = App.BaseRoute.extend({
    redirect : function() {
        this.transitionTo('public.login');
    }
});

App.PublicLoginRoute = App.BaseRoute.extend({

    renderTemplate : function(router, context) {
    this._super(router, context);
        this.render('publicLogin', {
            into : 'applicationHBS',
            outlet : 'appBODY'
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Based on release notes this._super() works as it used to, so no problem there. Also your example since fine by commenting out the setup/require part http://emberjs.jsbin.com/secufemi/1/edit .

Comment: unless `thatSuper.call(self, context);` within the `require` code part falls in the cases of calling `_super` out of line as mentioned here http://emberjs.com/blog/2014/03/30/ember-1-5-0-and-ember-1-6-beta-released.html

Comment: Can you slowly cut down the feature set of this application to see at what point it starts working again? You might first try a hello-world like app w/ your requireJS setup to see if that added complexity is at the root of your problem